# Converting a json value that keeps changing to int in c++

Tags: c++, json, parsing, int

Okay so i get this JSON object from my client:

```
{"command":"BrugerIndtastTF","brugerT":"\"10\"","brugerF":"\"20\""}
```

Then i need to use the int value from "brugerT", but as you can see it has "\"10\"" around it. When i code this in javascript i dont get this problem. Is there a way to only use the part of "brugerT" that says 10?

the code where *temp only should print the int value 10:

```
socket_->hub_.onMessage([this](
                   uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws,
                   char* message,
                   size_t length,
                   uWS::OpCode opCode
                   )
                    {

                 std::string data = std::string(message,length);                  
                std::cout << "web::Server:\t Data received: " << data << std::endl; 

                // handle manual settings

                std::cout << "Web::Server:\t Received request: manual. Redirecting message." << std::endl;

                json test1 = json::parse(data);
                auto test2 = test1.json::find("command");

                std::cout << "Web::Server:\t Test 1" << test1 << std::endl;

                std::cout << "Web::Server:\t Test 2" << *test2 << std::endl;

                if (*test2 =="BrugerIndtastTF")
                {
                        std::cout<<"Web::Server:\t BrugerIndtastTF modtaget" << std::endl;
                        auto temp= test1.json::find("brugerT");
                        auto humi= test1.json::find("brugerF");



                        std::cout << "Web::Server:\t temp: " << *temp << "humi: " << *humi << std::endl;
                }



                });
```

EDIT:
[Here you can see the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URTim.png)

it should just say: temp: 10 humi: 20

Comment: What does your `data` string look like? Can you provide the resp. console output of your snippet?

Comment: Well if I'm reading the doc correctly and if you are using the JSON library that I think you are then `temp->get<int>()` but I could be wrong. Try reading the doc yourself?

Comment: @Lucker10 console output is in the post now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the `string` value of `brugerT` and strip the `\"` out of the string and then convert the resulting `string` into a `int` with [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). You could even use a regular expression to find the integer inside the `string` and let that library figure out what is the best matching method. A regular expression for that would be something like: `([0-9]+)`

ps string [literal type 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) might be of some use when manually filtering out `\"`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string inputStr(R"("\"10\"")");

  regex matchStr(R"(([0-9]+))");
  auto matchesBegin = sregex_iterator(inputStr.begin(), inputStr.end(), matchStr);
  auto matchesEnd = sregex_iterator();

  for (sregex_iterator i = matchesBegin; i != matchesEnd; ++i) {
    cout << i->str() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay so im trying to do the following:
*temp is: "\"10\"" --
std:string tmp = *temp;
std:string str2 = tmp.substr(3,2);
 but when i print this i get nothing.

Comment: I'd prefer to clean the `data` string before you parse it to json (if possible)

Comment: @Mads Sander, that is some scary code with the now compileable statements and magic numbers. If you convert it to compileable code it "works" though:  0\.

Comment: @Lucker10 you could do that but I believe it is safer to sanitize the input after interpretation as JSON. Because you will need to code around situations where these characters are wanted if you strip the input before interpretation. It is trivial to extract the int from a string so I see no need to clean it before.

Comment: I've posted the terminal

Comment: @TarickWelling yes, you are right. Do you have access to the code which sends this message? If yes, fix it there